# SQL Access Create / Update / Delete table based on query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I want to populate table1 based on a query. The table is used and information is added to the table by users (comment- field).

The result of the query:

```
TAG_ID    CM_ID   PROP_ID

   1         1        5  
   1         2        3  
   2         1        2  
   2         2        20
```

Table1:

```
ID   TAG_ID   CM_ID    PROP_ID      COMMENT
1     1         1        5        comment 1 filled in by user
2     1         2        3        comment 1 filled in by user 
3     2         1        2        comment 1 filled in by user 
4     2         2        20       comment 1 filled in by user
```

The combination of TAG_ID / CM_ID / PROP_ID is unique.
If the combination does not exists => add
If the combination exists => leave as is (comment can be filled in by user and I don't want to loose the information)
if the combination is not present in the query => delete from table1

Thanks!

Comment: What you need is `MERGE`. Look it up in BOL

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If you show us what you've tired so far, you are more likely to get an answer.  SO can help with errors, but it isn't a code writing service.